# WebSphere equivalent in .NET

Tags: .net, enterprise, saas, enterprise-architect, appserver

Is there an equivalent in .NET to a websphere-style app server? Something that will manage all our WCF endpoints across multiple projects/solutions, track dependencies and versions, handle WS-Discovery (or WSDL or whatever)?

Ideally something F/OSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running WCF, you probably also are using Windows Server 2003 or 2008. The appserver type features in the .NET world are spread across IIS, MSMQ and COM+, which are bundled with the server, so free as in no additional cost after the server, but not necessarily free as in code you can read and modify.

These are two more opensource app servers for .NET
Base4 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base4_Application_Server
TNAPS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNAPS_Application_Server

Also, WCF is capable of speaking standards, so I suppose you could have a .NET WCF client invoke/send messages to JBoss, however, the rumor is that for all products of this sort, you get the best results from using a homogeneous stack-- the standards are good but not perfect.

Comment: Interesting, but neither seems to handle the specific thing I'm after; Lets say I have 20 WCF services, across 5 IIS servers. They're all interdependent. Further, they've cross-dependent by version. So Service 1 v1 is required for Service 2 v3, but v2 is required for v5. What can we use to manage all this? I realize I can roll my own via ws-discovery, but I'm guessing there's something already out there?

Comment: You asked three questions. I answered #1 and #3. I don't understand your other question. It almost sounds like you are asking about a requirements tracibility matrix, which is a topic a long way from selecting an inexpensive application server. You may want to post an additional question.

Comment: I'm not sure they're independent.. Let me rephrase a little bit. Say I have two IIS servers. Server 1 and Server 2. Server 1 hosts Service A, version 1.0. Server 2 hosts Service A, version 2.0. Now I have a client that (at runtime) decides it wants to use version 2.0. I see the appserver as the place where the client would say 'resolve me an endpoint that implements IServiceA, version 2.0. -- Layered on top would be security (can this client go there?), load balancing (which server in the farm that has this service is least-busy), etc.

Comment: That is a discussion about how to make discoverability "just work" In COM it "just worked" because the registry kept track of things, in plain vanilla .NET, it just works because of the assembly resolution (check bin, check gac, check the 4 part name, etc). With WCF, you can make discovarability happen, but it takes some help: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335779.aspx  and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg232769.aspx  That is discoverability where you very carefully set up services to be found by clients.

Comment: Right -- so appfabric looks like exactly what im after, but its azure-only.. Is there a self-hosted equivalent?

Comment: I don't have any exp with Azure or App Fabric, but it appears that it comes in 2 flavors Azure and self hosted and the self hosted on has fewer features (caching and WF features) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppFabric You'd get a better quality answer by asking a new question with the AppFabric or Azure tag.